# Export of plots fails in loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following loop:

```
for(planingPeriod in planingPeriods){
  png(paste(planingPeriod,".png",sep=""), width = 30, height = 2, units = 'in', res = 500)

  ggplot(data=datasetA, aes(x=as.factor(variable),y=count,fill = value)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity", width = 1) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#4ceb34","#ebd034","#eb34dc","#34ebc3","#3452eb","#eb3434"))

  dev.off()
}
```

It should export plots automatically. My problem is that the files are created but they do not contain any data (white pics without ANY content). I do not get any Warning/Error.
When I execute the code without the for loop then a plot is created. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: So if you assign a value to `planingPeriod` and just run the inside of the loop it works?

Comment: Note instead of `paste(...,sep="")` you can use the base function `paste0(...)`

Comment: Wrap your ggplot in print: `for(i in...){ png(...); print(ggplot....); dev.off() }`

Comment: that solved it! thank you